# Visual Studio 2008 Product Key in Registry?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, registry

I have a friend who needs to reinstall windows, but he can't find his VS2008 activation code/product key. Is there a way to look up which product key he entered when he last installed VS2008 in the registry? Any other method of finding the key is also welcome.

Comment: how is this programming related? This should be in the Visual Studio Product forums

Comment: @starko: I would categorize this as configuration of programming tools. I think it bares equal relevance to programming as Eclipse plugin setup, MySQL setup options, installing Subversion etc.

Comment: @cbrulak Consider it as a question..."How to write a program in c++ to get VS2008 activation code/product key from registry?? "!!.Now it comes in the scope right?..........just kidding ok.

Comment: The third point in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic is "software tools commonly used by programmers". If Visual Studio isn't a software tool commonly used by programmers, I've no idea what is.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### For 32 bit Windows:

Visual Studio 2003:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.0\Registration\PIDKEY

Visual Studio 2005:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Registration\PIDKEY

Visual Studio 2008:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Registration\PIDKEY

### For 64 bit Windows:

Visual Studio 2003:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.0\Registration\PIDKEY

Visual Studio 2005:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Registration\PIDKEY

Visual Studio 2008:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Registration\PIDKEY

### Notes:

- Data is a GUID without dashes. Put a dash ( – ) after every 5 characters to convert to product key.
- If PIDKEY value is empty try to look at the subfolders e.g.

  > ...\Registration\1000.0x0000\PIDKEY

  or

  > ...\Registration\2000.0x0000\PIDKEY

Comment: It also works for VS 2010, just use 10.0 instead of 7.0, 8.0 or 9.0.

Comment: Wish to have an update because there isn't such registry key for VS 2017

Answer (score 5):

I found the product key for Visual Studio 2008 Professional under a slightly different 
key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSDN\8.0\Registration\PIDKEY
```

it was listed without the dashes as stated above.

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2005:

> If you do have an installed Visual Studio 2005 however, and want to find out the serial number you’ve used to install it because you don’t have a clue where you put that shiny sticker, you can. It is, like most things in Windows, in the registry.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Registration\PIDKEY
>
> In order to convert the value in that key to an actual serial number you have to put a dash ( – ) after evert 5 characters of the code.

From: http://www.gooli.org/blog/visual-studio-2005-serial-number/

For Visual Studio 2008 it's supposed to be:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Registration\PIDKEY

However I noted that the the Data field for PIDKEY is only filled in the `1000.0x000` (or 2000.0x000) sub folder of the above paths.

Answer (score -2):

Just delete key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/VCExpress/9.0/Registration
```

Or run in command line:

```
reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VCExpress\9.0\Registration /f
```