# Change product key in Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2008, license-key

I erroneously used the same product key for VS2008 on two computers. I would like to change the key on one of them. Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529064/visual-studio-2008-product-key-in-registry) tells where I can find the key in registry, but I couldn't find anywhere on Internet if I may actually change that value in registry. There are some answers that changing the key is impossible. What should I do then, reinstall whole Visual Studio just to change the key?

How to replace product key for Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Is something broken or not working because you've entered the wrong key? You're completely legal as long as you *own* a sufficient number of licenses. It's not terribly relevant what key you've used for the installation. (That is, don't spend too much time fixing what isn't broken!)

Comment: Your comment made me call the local support by phone (not so painful as I imagined). The answer is short and not so sweet: must reinstall Visual Studio. I'll leave the question open, but there it is.

Comment: The license allows you to install VS on more than one machine.  I wouldn't lose any sleep over this.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the answer I expected. That's the way you handle it for most Microsoft software. That's why I was suggesting you simply ignore it if it wasn't actually causing you any problems. Thanks for posting what you've learned as confirmation, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT (see OP comments):

support solution: **reinstall**...

or

***[the following woks with Trial version (does not answer the question)]***

try `control panel->add/remove programs->change/remove->` enter a new product key

or

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0
               \Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite - ENU\setup.sdb
```

search for [`product key]` and change it

more info [here...](http://www.ceveni.com/2008/08/how-to-change-visual-studio-license-key.html)

Comment: I've stumbled on this page, but it relates to upgrading from Trial version. Additionally, my setup.sdb does not have [ product key] section, which gives me suspicions about this being the solution.

Comment: I found that section in my setup.sdb (final(not trial) version) that's why I posted this answer. Have you tried the add/remove programs?

Comment: Yes I did, there are no available fields to enter the key. I called support and got the answer: must reinstall the whole thing. :(